# Why is PyAutogui not installing onto my computer?

Tags: python, arduino, pip, pyautogui

I'm trying to install pyautogui on my laptop so I can use it to make a gesture-controlled system using an Arduino Uno and its giving me the below error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-sqzd6a\\pyautogui\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-sqzd6a\\pyautogui\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ukdpzd'
         cwd: c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-sqzd6a\pyautogui\
    Complete output (3 lines):
    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error in PyAutoGUI setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

please assist me in figuring out the problem

Comment: Python 2.7 has reached its end of life. Can you try with Python 3? The latest is Python 3.8.

Comment: I'm doing this project https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-python-tutorial 
It requires me to use version 2.7 because it says the later versions do not provide support the arduino libraries.